# help: heart in a box

Tags: magic

So, one of my main characters, 'Underneath' serves the 'old king', who lays among cobwebs and old scriptures underneath the cathedral of silence, bitter and crippled.
She provides him with snips of information she hears, or... 'food'. She does it against her will, as the old king has her heart in a box (literally) so she is... forced, to do his biding, or risk her heart being destroyed.

How could this plot mechanic work? could it? i intend to use this to explore certain places in the world, sort of using this as the 'B' plot to my main story 'A' plot. So the reader can get a feel of the world.

Comment: I'm afraid this kind of question isn't what WorldBuilding.SE is for. We can help you build your world, but we can't help you tell the story that takes place in it. You could make this on-topic by asking how your "heart-in-a-box" plot mechanic could work, however.

Comment: Thankyou for telling me! im new here so im still figuring things out

Comment: @Uncertainty If you haven't already, I really encourage you to take the quick site [Tour] as well as to review [What topics can I ask about here?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) in the site's [Help]. Enjoy your stay!

Comment: Why did you change the post so dramatically? If you have more than 1 question, you should ask in seperate posts. It gives each question a clean slate to start off on, and you don't invalidate answers. Your edit means that the answer to this question will have to be removed because it doesn't answer the question anymore, and along with it goes the author's hard work and any reputation they might have earned from it.

Comment: sorry ._. im new, if you cant tell... ill keep it in mind

Comment: Careful, I almost missed your comment. When you mention someone in a comment, they will get a notification. If you don't, they won't see it. For example, you get a notification in your inbox if I put @Uncertainy anywhere in my comment. If you don't mention anyone, the owner of the post will be notified. In this case, that is you. You don't get notified about your comments on own post, so you didn't get one when responding to me. The setup means that I don't have to @ mention you when commenting on your post, but you have to mention me when replying.

Comment: @Uncertainty No problem, we've all been there before. Stack Exchange can be hard to get used to because it is so different from other QA sites. If you ever need help, just look at the help menu, ask another user, or when you get enough reputation, you can ask in the chat.

Comment: I've rolled back your question to just before you changed it as you already have an (accepted) answer to that question. If you want to ask the question about beasts in the darkness, please ask a new question so as not to confuse things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a character who is bitter against established society, Then make it that her mother sold her daughters heart for a small boon.  Or Daddy could have sold it if you want the character to have issues with men.

Perhaps she sold her heart when she was younger for something (or some one) she really wanted, and now she feels that she was a fool to sell her own heart so cheap.

Or perhaps she sold her heart to save her family from certain death, she knows it was the right choice,  but she also feels guilty because she sometimes struggles with regret for making that choice, even if it was the right one.

Comment: omg i acc changed the question, because i realised it doesnt really fit into 'world bulding' but thankyou for the answer anyways!

Comment: I like how that could be used for character development?

Comment: @Uncertainty My recommendation is that you should rollback your edit and make a new question for the one about beasts in the dark. I could do it for you, but I want to leave the decision of what to do up to you.